# No files were found to deploy with search pattern when trying to SqlAzureDacpacDeployment with Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-server

I try to publish Dacpac file to Azure SQL.
I get Dacpac file published correctly to Azure DevOps. I see AzureSQL.dacpac under "drop" of Artifact.
However I get error and wondering why file cannot be found.

ERROR:

```
No files were found to deploy with search pattern d:\a\1\drop\AzureSQL.dacpacCheck out how to 
troubleshoot failures at https://aka.ms/sqlazuredeployreadme#troubleshooting-
```

CODE:

```
 - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
   inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/AzureSQL/bin/Release/'
      ArtifactName: 'drop'
      publishLocation: 'Container'

- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  inputs:
     azureSubscription: xxxxxx
     AuthenticationType: xxxxxx
     ServerName: xxxxxx
     DatabaseName: xxxxxx
     SqlUsername: xxxxxx
     SqlPassword: xxxxxx
     deployType: 'DacpacTask'
     DeploymentAction: 'Publish'
     DacpacFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/AzureSQL.dacpac'
     IpDetectionMethod: 'AutoDetect'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would lookup the dacpac file here: $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/drop/

UPDATE

As refering to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/build-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) article, i beleive you are able to download the artifact with

```
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
  inputs:
    buildType: 'current'
    downloadType: 'single'
    artifactName: 'drop'
    downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/drop/AzureSQL.dacpac'
```

and than access it from the downloadPath in SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1. And maybe you need to update the PathtoPublish in PublishBuildArtifacts@1 to

> '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/AzureSQL/bin/Release/AzureSQL.dacpac'